# Sorting out lists into nested lists

Tags: python

I am trying to figure out how to append elements from the list into a pattern where I put them into the nested lists.

For example:

```
members = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
no_of_teams = int(input('no. of teams? '))
teams = [ [ ] for _ in range(no_of_teams)]
```

So that my output will end up looking like this:

no_of_teams? 2

```
teams = [ [1, 3, 5, 7, 9], [2, 4, 6, 8]]
```

if the user enters 3 then it will look like this:

```
teams = [[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]
```

and for 7 it looks like

```
teams = [ [1, 8], [2, 9], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7] ]
```

Comment: Hint: use *slicing*.

Comment: What if the user enters 4 or 7?

Comment: if the user enters 3 then it will look like this. teams = [[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]] and for 7 it looks like teams = [ [1, 8], [2, 9], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7] ]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good way is to use slicing:

```
number = int(input(...))
members = list(range(1, 10))
chunks = len(members) // number
teams = [members[i*chunks:i*chunks+number]
         for i in range(number)]
```

You could also use step size instead:

```
teams = [members[i::number]
         for i in range(number)]
```

This will yield your desired output:

- in each iteration, we start the slice at the next item in the list
- the slice goes up in `n` steps

So, if `n` is 3, the 1st iteration will give a slice containing the indexes 0, 3, 6, 9..... since the step size is 3
The 2nd iteration gives indexes 1, 4, 7...
The 3rd iteration gives indexes 2, 5, 8...
Iteration stops here at the 3rd since `n` dictates this too.

Comment: Thank You. This has helped a lot for me.

Comment: Hi @Garesh if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can slice it into the correct number of sublists:

```
slice_size = int(len(members) / no_of_teams)
teams = []
for i in range(no_of_teams):
    teams.append( members[i * slice_size: i * slice_size + slice_size]
```

Answer (score 1):

Given there are `n` teams, we can use list comprehension to construct `n` slices, such that the *i*-th element is assigned to the *i mod n*-th team:

```
teams = [ members[i::n] for i in range(n) ]
```

For example:

```
>>> n= 1
>>> [ members[i::n] for i in range(n) ]
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
>>> n= 2
>>> [ members[i::n] for i in range(n) ]
[[1, 3, 5, 7, 9], [2, 4, 6, 8]]
>>> n= 3
>>> [ members[i::n] for i in range(n) ]
[[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]
```

Comment: Thank You for the help sir. I spent hours on figuring it out.

Answer (score 1):

You can slice the list:

```
teams = [members[i::no_of_teams] for i in range(no_of_teams)]
```

Comment: Thank You. This has helped me a lot. Gave a like to your answer as well.